# Как правильно внедрить в сайт на angular1 код RTB (Рекламная сеть Яндекс)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, реклама

Сам код выглядит так:

```
<div id="yandex_rtb_1"></div>
```

C дивом понятно, помещаем в `body`, а вот сам скрипт я так понимаю надо в `runBlock`? Пробовал через `$stateChangeSuccess`, но тогда пишет:

> this.document of null

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(w, d, n, s, t) {
            w[n] = w[n] || [];
            w[n].push(function() {
                Ya.Context.AdvManager.render({
                    blockId: "R-A-12345-1",
                    renderTo: "yandex_rtb_R-A-12345-1",
                    horizontalAlign: true,
                    async: true
                });
            });
            t = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            s = d.createElement("script");
            s.type = "text/javascript";
            s.src = "//an.yandex.ru/system/context.js";
            s.async = true;
            t.parentNode.insertBefore(s, t);
        })(this, this.document, "yandexContextAsyncCallbacks");
</script>
```

Comment: 1. А зачем его в run-блок? 2. Замени `this` на `window`.

Comment: @Qwertiy 2 спс с $window заработало. 1 А куда надо правильно?